# Unhandled exception while doing SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have configured a console application in the task scheduler.

The console application uses SqlBulkCopy to insert data into the sql table by reading the same from csv file.

The problem is the job randomly throws exception that I am not able to catch using try catch.

However it gets logged into event viewer as:

```
Application: ApplicationName.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info:  System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException
Stack:
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
   at SDO.Repository.Repository`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].SaveChanges()
   at SDO.Business.SolutionDB.SolverProcess.ProcessConsoleOutput(System.Object, System.Diagnostics.DataReceivedEventArgs)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.OutputReadNotifyUser(System.String)
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.FlushMessageQueue()
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.ReadBuffer(System.IAsyncResult)
   at System.IO.Stream+ReadWriteTask.InvokeAsyncCallback(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.IO.Stream+ReadWriteTask.System.Threading.Tasks.ITaskCompletionAction.Invoke(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageTwo()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Finish(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(System.Threading.Tasks.Task ByRef)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

The task scheduler job just get stuck at this point. 
Just FYI I am using entity framework 6 database first approach.
As we insert more than 30k of data in one table so I went with the SqlBulkCopy approach and it is performing quite good. However this is the only issue that we are facing.

Comment: Have you check the file data? Usually the problem derives from csv data.

Comment: The same file gets uploaded fine some times. This is random behavior.

Comment: The same file may have not the same data. Have you debug the file?

Comment: Actually we have scenarios on which the file gets generated. The row count everything is perfect. I debugged it however while debugging it got uploaded successfully. However when the same thing is done via job scheduler it fails and just logs the above exception in event viewer. Also to clarify it works most of the time through job scheduler as well.